# TimePicker has hidden margins or padding - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, timepicker

Ok, I've looked around and around and cannot figure out what to do with this.

TimePicker has some hidden spacing around it. When I put two TimePickers one under another as:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#440044"
    android:layout_margin="-30dp"
    android:padding="-30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePickerA"
        android:scaleY="0.50"
        android:scaleX="0.50"
        android:layout_margin="-30dp"
        android:padding="-30dp"
        android:background="#989898"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePickerB"
        android:scaleY="0.50"
        android:scaleX="0.50"
        android:layout_margin="-30dp"
        android:padding="-30dp"
        android:background="#989898"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the TimePickers still have a huge amount of space around each of them. Notice I even tried using both negative margins and padding in both the TimePickers and the parent LinearLayout. These have no impact at all on the spacing around the TimePickers.

[image: Image of TimerPickers]

The scaleX and Y are obviously to reduce the size of these ridiculously huge TimePickers!

I'm trying to avoid making a custom if possible.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem** is that when you use `android:scaleY="0.50"` and `android:scaleX="0.50"` you don't decrease the View at his half, you just re-scale it. That means your `TimePicker` still have the same width and height but the drawing area will be reduced to half (half X and half Y).

See the image below, the *blue rectangle* represent the real `width` and `height` of your View (the TimePicker).

[image]

**As a solution**:

I think it's better if you make a custom one.

Otherwise as workaround you can use a `RelativeLayout` and play with margins, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="#440044"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePickerA"
        android:scaleY="0.50"
        android:scaleX="0.50"
        android:background="#989898"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePickerB"
        android:scaleY="0.50"
        android:scaleX="0.50"
        android:background="#989898"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timePickerA"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="-80dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PS:** I don't guarantee that you'll have the same result in different screen density/size.